Operator on reduced group $C^*$-algebra induces operator on von Neumann algebra
Let $\Gamma$ be a discrete group. Consider its reduced group $C^* $-algebra $C_\lambda^* (\Gamma)$ and von Neumann algebra $L(\Gamma) = C_\lambda^* (\Gamma)'' \subseteq B(\ell^2(\Gamma))$.
Let $T:C_\lambda^* (\Gamma) \rightarrow C_\lambda^* (\Gamma)$ be a (completely) bounded linear map. Is there a way to extend $T$ to a (completely) bounded linear map $\tilde{T}:L(\Gamma) \rightarrow L(\Gamma)$?
If we instead consider $C_\lambda^* (\Gamma)$ represented in its universal Hilbert space $H_U$ and let $M:=C_\lambda^* (\Gamma)'' \subseteq B(H_U)$ (this is the enveloping von Neumann algebra construction). We have an isomorphism $M \cong C_\lambda^* (\Gamma)^{**}$ and thus from a map $T:C_\lambda^* (\Gamma) \rightarrow C_\lambda^* (\Gamma)$ we can induce $T^{**}:C_\lambda^* (\Gamma)^{**} \rightarrow C_\lambda^* (\Gamma)^{**}$ which is the same as a map $M \rightarrow M$.
In this case, the question becomes if $L(\Gamma) \cong M$ and if the isomorphism is nice enough so that the induced map is something one can work with.
However, I think things would be cleaner if the universal representation is avoided and am not sure how it behaves regarding complete boundness.

If you want $\tilde{T}$ to also be normal, as in the double dual case, then no. For example, if $\Gamma$ is an infinite amenable group, then the trivial representation of $\Gamma$ extends to a unital $\ast$-homomorphism $T: C_\lambda^\ast(\Gamma) \to \mathbb{C}$. By embedding $\mathbb{C}$ into $C_\lambda^\ast(\Gamma)$, we may assume $T$ is a unital $\ast$-homomorphism from $C_\lambda^\ast(\Gamma)$ to itself. But if a normal extension $\tilde{T}$ exists, it must be a normal unital $\ast$-homomorphism from $L(\Gamma)$ to $\mathbb{C}$. As $L(\Gamma)$ is a diffuse tracial von Neumann algebra, no such normal unital $\ast$-homomorphism can exist.

This example wouldn’t work without normality assumptions, and with the complete boundedness version of your question, since $L(\Gamma)$ is injective (in the category of operator spaces and completely bounded maps) when $\Gamma$ is amenable, so a completely bounded extension exists solely due to injectivity.

Also, it is never the case that $C_\lambda^\ast(\Gamma)^{\ast\ast} \simeq L(\Gamma)$ unless $\Gamma$ is finite, because $C_\lambda^\ast(\Gamma)^{\ast\ast}$ always have type I summands but $L(\Gamma)$ is diffuse whenever $\Gamma$ is infinite.

Thank you so much again! By this point I am going to put you in the acknowledgements of my thesis, if you allow me.

@TomásPacheco You’re welcome. I don’t think I’ve done much, but you’re certainly welcome to put me in acknowledgements if you so wish.
